# Bluetooth Communication from Xamarin to C# Console App

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I am developing an Xamarin application (currently focused on Android but will eventually support iOS) that communicates via bluetooth to a nearby C# console application. They both act as a client/server as they need to send messages back and forth.

The read code for the Android implementation is as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;

// Listen to the input stream while connected
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        // Read from the InputStream
        bytes = this.InStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var message = new Java.Lang.String(buffer, 0, bytes);

         // TODO: Notify the UI of the message
    }
    catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
    {
        // TODO: Show some error
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that since I am only reading a buffer size of `1024` I am only getting partial messages for anything over `1024` bytes. Using a `DataWriter` (as shown below in the console application) would be ideal for me, but it is not available for an Android implementation using Xamarin.

The write code for the Android application is as follows:

```
try
{
    this.OutStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    // TODO: Notify the UI            
}
catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
{
    // TODO: Show some error        
}
```

Now, for the console application the read code is as follows:

```
// socket here is a Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket
var reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        uint readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
        uint currentLength = reader.ReadUInt32();

        await reader.LoadAsync(currentLength);

        string message = reader.ReadString(readLength);
        Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: Show some error
    }
}
```

The problem here, is the the `await reader.LoadAsync(currentLength)` is never resolved. I am guessing that is because the Android app is only sending the message and not the length, *then* the message. I can get rid of the second await and use a buffer size of `1024` as I am in the Android application, but I will again be getting partial messages. Simply increasing the buffer size to get a bigger message is another option, but that sounds incorrect to me.

And the write code for the console application:

```
// socket here is a Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket
var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream)

writer.WriteUInt32((uint)message.Length);
writer.WriteString(message);

try
{
    await writer.StoreAsync();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // TODO: Show some error
}
```

I am unsure of the changes I need to make to be able to send and receive complete messages back and forth on both applications. As I stated before, the implementation of the console application will need to support iOS bluetooth communication as well.